# Visual Composer Prestashop Array to string conversion

Tags: php, prestashop, php-7

After installing Visual Composer module for Prestashop 1.6.1.7 with PHP 7 I am getting this error:

> Notice w linii 74 w pliku
>   /public_html/modules/jscomposer/include/classes/shortcodes/vc-row.php
>       [8] Array to string conversion

The problem is with this line:

```
$param_value = isset( $$param['param_name'] ) ? $$param['param_name'] : '';
```

I guess that is a PHP problem. What can be wrong with this particular line?

Here is more from that file:

```
if ( isset( $this->settings['params'] ) ) {
    $inner = '';
    foreach ( $this->settings['params'] as $param ) {
        $param_value = isset( $$param['param_name'] ) ? $$param['param_name'] : '';
        if ( is_array( $param_value ) ) {
            // Get first element from the array
            reset( $param_value );
            $first_key = key( $param_value );
            $param_value = $param_value[$first_key];
        }
        $inner .= $this->singleParamHtmlHolder( $param, $param_value );
    }
    $output .= $inner;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `!empty()` instead of `isset()` because `isset()` not use for array

```
$param_value = !empty($param['param_name'] ) ? $param['param_name'] : '';
```

Comment: Sadly, problem still occurs.

Comment: try now... `$$` change to `$`